# Is it possible to exclude a file or folder from being synced, while it is in a directory that was synced?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, folder

I synced a folder called "travel".  I want to exclude a file in this folder from being synced.  Is this possible?  Do the other big syncers, like dropbox and mozy, have this feature?

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu One does not currently support this; a workaround would be to move the folder out from the folder it is currently in (and point a symlink at it from the synced folder if necessary), or rename it to something unique and add that name to the 'ignore' pattern list (**this second way is rather tricky; please read the note below**).

Here's how to do the first: assuming `travel` is in a directory called `misc`, and that the subdirectory of `travel` you don't want synced is called `huge`, open a terminal (Applications » Accessories » Terminal) , and type:

```
 cd misc
 mv travel/huge .travel_huge
 ln -s ../.travel_huge tavel/huge
```

note that `.travel_huge` is a hidden directory, so you wouldn't normally see it in the nauitlus and file pickers.

---

[image: dangerous bend]

Here's how you do the second, asuming the unique name you chose for `huge` is `huge-pics-of-acorn-trees-february-2011`: first, edit ~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf (you can use Applications » Accessories » Text Editor) and add the following to the `__main__` section (if the file doesn't exist, prepend the following by a line containing just `[__main__]`):

```
ignore = \A#.*\Z
         \A.*~\Z
         \A.*\.py[oc]\Z
         \A.*\.sw[nopx]\Z
         \A.*\.swpx\Z
         \A\..*\.tmp\Z
         \Ahuge-pics-of-acorn-trees-february-2011\Z
```

or you could simply rename the folder to something already covered by the current `ignore` list, such as `huge.tmp` or `huge.pyc`, but I doubt you'll like that.

Please do note, however, that the second method described is rather fragile: make sure you've updated the configuration file and restarted syncdaemon (with `u1sdtool -q; u1sdtool -c`) before creating the toplevel directory. If the directory already exists, do not move it to the ignored name with the syncdaemon running; rather, stop syncdaemon, rename the folder, edit the ignore list, and start syncdaemon. Alternatively move the folder out of the synced hierarchy, and rename it before moving it back in. Otherwise it might not work as you'd expect it to, if at all.

---

I understand dropbox has the feature (I've seen a video explaining how to use it), but I haven't checked and it might only be in a beta or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

In answer to your question about the other big syncers: Dropbox doesn't appear to have a way to selectively ignore specific files/file types, but [**this post**](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=52360#post-387887) by **Dylan R.** provides a way to selectively ignore folders.

In a nutshell, it goes like this:

1. Back it up, just in case :)
2. Quit whatever application may be using/writing to the folder
3. Move the folder that you want to not sync out of dropbox
4. Let that sync
5. Make a folder with the same exact name in the same exact place
6. Use Selective Sync to stop syncing that (empty) folder.
   It will remove the (now-empty) folder.
7. Move your original folder
   back in.

It'll get a gray minus icon, and is no longer syncing. (the
    empty folder has to remain on Dropbox, but it's empty, so not taking
    up space)

Comment: please mind the tags, it's ubuntu-one related question.

Comment: @shookees please mind the questions content - I quote from the question: "Do the other big syncers, like dropbox and mozy, have this feature?" Thanks for the downvote ):

Comment: it doesn't qualify as an answer to his question, more like a comment.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clear it's not about ubuntu-one. I thought about making it a comment, but there was rather too much content. I'd found this question looking for an answer to the same but about Dropbox, so I thought it a good place to put the answer I subsequently found. Could have asked a new question, but thought there's no need, when it's already asked here.