# Ignore files in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, python

I found that I can use:

```
ignore.default = \A#.*\Z
                 \A.*~\Z
                 \A.*\.py[oc]\Z
                 \A.*\.sw[nopx]\Z
                 \A.*\.swpx\Z
                 \A\..*\.tmp\Z
                 \A.*\.git\Z
```

In /etc/xdg/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf to ignore files. I'm not really up on regex so I tried to add the last line to ignore the .git folder. It doesn't appear to be working though. Anyone have a correct solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to exclude a file or folder from being synced, while it is in a directory that was synced?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26658/is-it-possible-to-exclude-a-file-or-folder-from-being-synced-while-it-is-in-a-di)

Comment: This question is not about *how* to ignore files/folders, I know that. This question is more specifically about the regex required to ignore the .git folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine suggested \A.git\Z for the .git folder. It seems to work effectively. The end result was the following ignore.default in /etc/xdg/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf:

```
ignore.default = \A#.*\Z
                 \A.*~\Z
                 \A.*\.py[oc]\Z
                 \A.*\.sw[nopx]\Z
                 \A.*\.swpx\Z
                 \A\..*\.tmp\Z
                 \A\.git\Z
```