# How do I keep the Thunderbird profile in sync between multiple computers?

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird

I'd like to find a definitive solution to automatically keep my Thunderbird profile in sync between my laptop and my desktop computer.

- I'm using IMAP, so keeping the e-mail itself in sync is not an issue
- I can use Ubuntu One for the contacts, so that should not be an issue, either.

However, there are [a bunch of other files and folders in the Thunderbird profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Files_and_folders_in_the_profile), and I'm not sure which ones I should keep in sync and which ones I shouldn't bother about.

Ideally, I'd like to use Ubuntu One to mark the required ones for syncing, but I would appreciate any help in deciding which ones exactly need to be synced.

Comment: I've noticed that this might be tricky to do with Ubuntu One, as it does not allow selective syncing of subfolders or files within a folder marked for syncing (http://askubuntu.com/questions/26658/is-it-possible-to-exclude-a-file-or-folder-from-being-synced-while-it-is-in-a-d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I can't sync individual files with Ubuntu One, only full folders, so in short, what I'm trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is possible to use links in your filesystem. So the point I'm aiming at is, can you possibly put the *.thunderbird* directory onto a fileserver and link to it?

I have the same problem, but from time to time it is enough for me to copy it directly onto an USB Drive and plug it into another computer of mine.

Just my 2 Cents